# Drupal site moved causing issues rendering images

Tags: media

I received a source code and DB. The site is in Drupal . I upload the site on IIS and DB(with default charset UTF-8).

Now what the problem we are facing is that we are unable to see some of the images. As i checked i find out that the image store in the folder is with the name having special characters can not be read.

And the image tag showing the image path with the image name in Arabic can any one tell how to fix this.

But in the images folder this image is with special characters name. If i upload new image in English name it is perfectly working fine.

My question is how to fix this blunder. Mysql is in utf 8 charset.

Comment: Are you using a CDN or other proxy with the new site? It's not unusual for these to have restrictions on characters in URLs. And for that reason it's a good idea to transliterate special characters when files are uploaded. See https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration

Comment: Yes there is a proxy server in our organization. Kindly help me with the solution.

Comment: How many files are involved? If there's not too many the simplest fix would be to install transliteration and re-upload them.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong There are so many images :(

Comment: Last time I had this problem I think I ended up writing a custom PHP script to update all the entries in the file_managed table. I think you just need to ensure there are no non-ASCII characters in the uri column. But it was quite a while ago. Hopefully someone else has such a script they can supply.